# Proxychains equivalent for Windows?

Tags: windows, proxy, socks

Proxychains is a unix tool that can proxy applications through SOCKS proxies:

```
proxychains wget www.google.com
```

I look for Proxychains equivalent for Windows. I need to proxify a single application only, and not the whole system.

I also need a CLI and not GUI solution.

Comment: "Find me a product that does X" is generally off-topic for Server Fault. If you can rephrase your question in the form of a *problem* (***WHY*** do you need this tool?) we might be able to help you out...

Comment: This Chinese closed-source free app does exactly that and it works https://www.sockscap64.com/en/

Answer (score -1):

I don't know of an equivalent. In Windows you only have two choices:

1. The system proxy (This is the one you see when in the Internet Options panel)
2. An application embedded proxy. Obviously this is reliant on a developer implementing such a feature.

The only way round this that I could think of would be to run a local proxy which does rule based forwarding. Perhaps it would help if you told us a little more about the problem you're facing.

Comment: That said, it looks like app does it: http://www.proxycap.com/ Disclaimer: I just Googled and found that.

Comment: yeah, there is also `proxifier`, but both of them are GUI tools. I need a CLI tool.

Comment: @iTayb Well, that's not what you said. Anyway, as with SO pure product recommendations are off topic here I'm afraid. There is no native way, though

Comment: Yeah, forgot to mention that. I was sure that a port for proxychains is available. maybe not.